# Render Partial View dynamically by passing input Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Created a Partial View _AvailableOptions.cshtml and  View CustomProducts.cshtml.
Now based on values of the the Model, CustomProducts.cshtml we may or may not load/show _AvailableOptions.cshtml. If loading then partial view must be render based on the input ProductID to show similar options dynamically

```
if(ProductId != 0)
   @Html.Partial("_AvailableOptions", SimilarProducts)
```

How to get the SimilarProducts Model from Server . Input parameter is ProductId to load the model.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

you need your view model to store SimilarProducts.

So in your controller you would have

```
if(ProductId != 0)
   {
      ViewModel.SimilarProducts = //Some service method that loads products
   }
```

then in your view you would simply do

```
if(ProductId != 0)
   @Html.Partial("_AvailableOptions", model.SimilarProducts)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a shared partial view only and get results during runtime..Actually to make things simple I have one if condition..but there are many parameters right device type also. I just need a solution to call and then load the partial view..One option is making Ajax call..but looking for a better solution